# Retrieving previous thursday and previous wednesday

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I am attempting to fetch the previous Thursday and the previous Wednesday based on a thursday date (for example 2024-01-18). I have tried the following queries:

For the previous Thursday:

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('week', '2024-01-18'::date) - INTERVAL '5 days' AS previous_wednesday, -- not working
  date_trunc('week', '2024-01-18'::date) - INTERVAL '4 days' AS previous_thursday;
```

db fidle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9GFNcJ81QfspGezYxhMib1/0

Which gives me

| previous_wednesday | previous_thursday |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-10T00:00:00.000Z | 2024-01-11T00:00:00.000Z |

Expected result :

| previous_wednesday | previous_thursday |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-17T00:00:00.000Z | 2024-01-11T00:00:00.000Z |

I would like assistance to find the desired result.

Comment: A week has 7 days, not 4.

Comment: BTW, previous Wednesday, is that the day before, or the Wednesday in previous week?

Comment: It's the day before

Comment: A Wednesday is 5 days back from Monday, a Thursday is 4 days back from Monday. Makes sense, but it doesn't get the most recent Wednesday and Thursday, but instead the ones from previous week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function can give you the `numeric` day of the week. You can use it in a [`case` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) to move back accordingly, or combine with modulo [`%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) operator: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0GzD7PUX)

```sql
SELECT 
  to_char(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD, Day'),
  -((extract(dow from my_date)+3)%7+1)::int+my_date::date AS previous_wednesday,
  -((extract(dow from my_date)+2)%7+1)::int+my_date::date AS previous_thursday
FROM generate_series('2024-01-15'::date,'2024-01-21','1d')_(my_date);
```

| to_char | previous_wednesday | previous_thursday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-15, Monday | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 |
| 2024-01-16, Tuesday | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 |
| **2024-01-17, Wednesday** | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 |
| **2024-01-18, Thursday** | **2024-01-17** | 2024-01-11 |
| **2024-01-19, Friday** | **2024-01-17** | **2024-01-18** |
| 2024-01-20, Saturday | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-18 |
| 2024-01-21, Sunday | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-18 |

Or you can [use a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77829394/1) that given a date up to Wednesday/Thursday shifts it back to previous week before you `date_trunc()`, then put your output Wed/Thu in that resulting week.

```sql
SELECT to_char(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD, Day'),
       date_trunc('week',-3+my_date::date)+'2d' AS previous_wednesday,
       date_trunc('week',-4+my_date::date)+'3d' AS previous_thursday
FROM generate_series('2024-01-15'::date,'2024-01-21','1d')_(my_date);
```

Comment: `-a::int+b::date` is a slightly shorter way of `b::date-a::int*interval '1 day'` thanks to `+` operator behaviour. Adding an `int` to a `date` with a `+` automatically assumes it means an `interval` of that many *days*, even if that `int` is negative, making it effectively a subtraction. An actual subtraction with a `-` doesn't work like that, so the subtrahend needs to be "manually" made into an `interval`.

Answer (score 0):

If the given date is always a thursday:

```sql
SELECT 
      '2024-01-18'::date - INTERVAL '1 days' AS previous_wednesday,
      '2024-01-18'::date - INTERVAL '7 days' AS previous_thursday;
```

No need for date_trunc, which would set the date to the start of the given week before adding/subtracting the interval.

---

If the given date isn't always a thursday, you may want to use date_trunc to start your calulcation always from monday of the given date.

```sql
    SELECT 
      date_trunc('week','2024-01-16'::date) + INTERVAL '2 days' AS current_wednesday, --wednesday of the given week
      date_trunc('week','2024-01-17'::date) + INTERVAL '3 days' AS current_thursday, -- thursday of the given week
      date_trunc('week','2024-01-17'::date) - INTERVAL '4 days' AS previous_thursday; -- thursday of the previous week
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_trunc('week', dt + interval '-3 days') + interval '2 days' -- prevWednesday
date_trunc('week', dt + interval '-4 days') + interval '3 days' -- prevThursday
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/fekFlsRF

To explain how this works let's first consider how to use `date_trunc()` so that we can make it use Wednesday, or effectively any other day, as the logical start of week. By "truncate" we define that as requiring a series of consecutive dates running from Wednesday through Tuesday to all collapse backward to the Wednesday starting point. To accomplish it with the built-in function we need to initially slide all dates in reverse by two days (the difference between Wednesday and Monday) and then after doing the truncate operation add the two days back in.

```
date_trunc('week', dt + interval '-2 days') + interval '2 days' -- truncToWednesday
date_trunc('week', dt + interval '-3 days') + interval '3 days' -- truncToThursday
```

There's only a minor change in the code between those two examples. The distinction lies in needing to treat a Wednesday as falling backward an entire week rather returning the same date as happens with truncating. To do that we can just slide left an extra day. Every other date in the input range will still be in the original truncation week and so their output is unchanged. But for a Wednesday going back one additional day causes it to fall into the prior week which is then pulled backward a full week earlier than it would have been otherwise, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: I like the idea but neither the syntax nor the output seem correct.

Comment: @Zegarek The fiddle above produces the same results as your own answer.

Comment: The one you [added later](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77829394/4), yes, but now it doesn't match what you presented in your answer, leaving the syntax problem: `interval '2' days` is still incorrect - for some reason you corrected that in the fiddle but not here.

Comment: I also don't really understand leaving the field name in a comment and letting it end up unnamed `?column?`. That's not unlike using cryptic variable names and explaining them in comments instead of naming them properly in the first place - Martin wouldn't be pleased. That's also corrected in [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j9jA-rYO) but not here. A side-question: is your screen less than the 72 db<>fiddle lines high on default res+ppi+zoom and is that why you added all those newlines?

Comment: @Zegarek My original version of the query was pasted from a working fiddle. I've just now realized that `day` and `days` are not interchangeable. I thought I had even confirmed as Postgres is not my native platform. It would have been helpful if you had simply pointed that out. I guess I had inadvertently tweaked it to be more verbose. In my rush I hadn't realized those empty lines were there. It's definitely curious now that I think about it. This expression is useful beyond `select` output and most developers can handle details like that. Sorry, but you do seem a bit pedantic.

Answer (score -1):

See example

`Previous wednesday` is different for `monday` and `friday` of the same week.
This is while you do not get expected output.

```
    SELECT id,dt
        ,case when to_char(dt,'dy') in('thu','fri','sat','sun') then
            date_trunc('week', dt) + INTERVAL '2 days'
         else
            date_trunc('week', dt) - INTERVAL '5 days' 
         end  AS previous_wednesday
        ,case when to_char(dt,'dy') in('fri','sat','sun') then
            date_trunc('week', dt) + INTERVAL '3 days' 
         else
            date_trunc('week', dt) - INTERVAL '4 days' 
         end AS previous_thursday
         -- for clarity
        ,to_char(dt,'dy') dy
        ,date_trunc('week', dt)  AS trunc_week
        ,extract(dow from dt) down
     from test;
```

Result is

| id | dt | previous_wednesday | previous_thursday | dy | trunc_week | down |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-15 | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 | mon | 2024-01-15 | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-01-16 | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 | tue | 2024-01-15 | 2 |
| 3 | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-11 | wed | 2024-01-15 | 3 |
| 4 | **2024-01-18** | **2024-01-17** | 2024-01-11 | thu | 2024-01-15 | 4 |
| 5 | 2024-01-19 | 2024-01-17 | **2024-01-18** | fri | 2024-01-15 | 5 |
| 6 | 2024-01-20 | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-18 | sat | 2024-01-15 | 6 |
| 7 | 2024-01-21 | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-18 | sun | 2024-01-15 | 0 |
| 8 | 2024-01-22 | 2024-01-17 | 2024-01-18 | mon | 2024-01-22 | 1 |

[View on Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5HvoEuL-)